# How can I get the title of a dynamically generated html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, title

I have the following code:

```
for(var i = 0;i < choices.length; i++){
     var $plans = $("<li id='entirePlan' class='Solution_ID'></li>").html('<p id="plan_id" class="plan_class">Plan: '+(i+1)+'</p>');
}
```

This creates up to three different plans on my website labeled accordingly. (there can be 1 plan, 2 plans, or 3 plans). If all three exist it looks like

Plan: 1

-----plan info here----

Plan: 2

-----plan info here----

Plan: 3

-----plan info here----

I want to be able to check the info in each plan and if it equals certain conditions, hide that plan. like this:

```
if(myCondition === something){
    if(plan1 exists){
         //hide plan 1
    }
}else if(myCondition === something){
     if(plan2 exists){
         //hide plan 2
    }
}else if(myCondition === something){
     if(plan3 exists){
         //hide plan 3
    }
}
```

However, I am not able to get the number of the plan in order to hide it. that's the only difference between the dynamically generated plans. i've tried the following:

```
$('p#plan_id.plan_class'))
$('#plan_id'))
$('.plan_class'))
$('#plan_id.plan_class'))
```

and then each of those with .html() or .text() on the end of them. I cannot get what plan number it is. I thought about trying to do something like :first, :second, :third, but couldn't get the value that way either.

I'm working in .js file, but prefer to use jquery first. javascript as a last resort. Advice?

--update: 
I tried the answer by Luizgrs also. I tried adding a data-number to both my

with my title and next to the solution ID. I tested in console.log to see if i was getting what i needed. I used:

```
console.log("plan?", $('.Solution_ID').data('number'));
console.log("plan?", $('.Solution_ID[data-number=1]'));
console.log("plan?", $('.plan_class').data('number'));
console.log("plan?", $('.plan_class[data-number=1]'));
```

and i got:

[image]
the only place i see anything remotely like what i need in that object is under childElementcount = 1. I tried appending childElementcount to the end of the calls above but got an error.

I tried typeoneerror's suggestion solution below using console.log to see if i could get what i wanted:

```
console.log("plan?", $('#entirePlan_1 p'));
console.log("plan?", $('#entirePlan_1 p').text());
console.log("plan?", $('#entirePlan_1 p').html());
```

Results: [image]
Not working guys and I don't know why..

Comment: Do you have a working sample up online or on jsbin so we can have a look? A bit difficult to understand from the question.

Comment: You couldn't use few id's on one page

Comment: So you want to get the plan based on its index number, right? Guessing at syntax like `:first :second :third` isn't a useful approach to problem solving. There's ample documentation for [DOM selection](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you'll have `choices.length` number of `li` tags with the same "id", namely, *entirePlan*. You probably want those ID's to be unique. You could append the `i` to the id and remove the `p`'s id as well...

```
for (var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
     var $plans = $("<li id='entirePlan_'" + (i + 1) + " class='Solution_ID'></li>").html('<p class="plan_class">Plan: ' + (i + 1) + '</p>');
}
```

Then your li's would look similar to:

```
<li id='entirePlan_1' class='Solution_ID'>
```

and you can "select" them via jQuery like so:

```
$('#entirePlan_1')
$('#entirePlan_2')
// etc
```

and to get the text in the `p` tag:

```
$('#entirePlan_1 p').text() // Plan: 1
```

Comment: i tried it and it wasn't working for me. I added my testing to my original question so you can see what it gave me in the developer tools. When I expanded that arrow I couldn't find my results in a place to pull from.

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit all over the place. You need to post your actual code somewhere so we can see what you're missing. I think we've answered your question, but it doesn't look like you understand how HTML or jQuery selectors work, so I'd recommend reading about those.

Comment: i'm going to keep trying, obviously, because i need to figure it out. but I did exactly what yall suggested and it didn't work, so I'm not sure why you said i don't know how selectors work.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you further without seeing actual working code. "Did it exactly" is relative. You may have done exactly what we suggested, but perhaps there's an error you are over-looking in code we haven't seen yet. Hence, post it live so we can debug. Otherwise, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Use data attributes. This is the feature created to add specific information to the HTML elements.

Let's suppose you end-up with the following HTML:

```
<li class="Solution_ID"><p ...></li>
<li class="Solution_ID"><p ...></li>
<li class="Solution_ID"><p ...></li>
```

Add a new attribute named `data-number`

```
<li class="Solution_ID" data-number="1"><p ...></li>
<li class="Solution_ID" data-number="2"><p ...></li>
<li class="Solution_ID" data-number="3"><p ...></li>
```

You can retrieve that value using jQuery using the `.data()` method:

```
$('.Solution_ID').data('number') //will retrieve 1, 2 or 3
```

or Select a specific plan:

```
$('.Solution_ID[data-number=2]');
```

Also pay attention to the IDs you're using, do not repeat them!

Comment: $('.Solution_ID[data-number=2]'); doesn't appear to work, neither does $('.plan_class[data-number=2]');

Comment: it does work, are you sure the attributes are there?